# Changing Date Parameter to Day Before

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, date, parameters, linq-to-sql

In short I have a stored procedure which accept a date parameter. This stored procedure is being called using Linq-to-SQL.

Procedure Code:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_Artemis_Tracking_SalesData] 
    @ShopID int, 
    @StartDate Date, 
    @EndDate Date, 
    @Daily bit 
AS 
BEGIN 
    SET NOCOUNT ON; 
    SELECT @EndDate;

    ....
END
```

If I call the procedure using the following

```
Dim Var = MyProc(#3/1/2021#, Today)
```

It passes the two dates seen as `3/1/2021 00:00:00` and `3/11/2021 00:00:00` (today is the 11th) but the parameters in SQL are getting the second variable as `3/10/2021` (the day BEFORE)

BUT

If I change the call to

```
Dim Var = MyProc(#3/1/2021#, Today.ToShortDateString)
```

then SQL Server sees the second variable as `3/11/2021`...

This is also true if I pass it as `#3/11/2021#` but if I use the `Today` function or actually any variable typed as Date it gets pushed back to the day before.

Side note: If I add an hour to the date, so that I pass `Today.AddHour(1)` then I get the 11th again in SQL

Help!

Comment: Sounds like you have a `</<=` problem. But why would you pass a date as a string anyway?

Comment: Your passing in a full DateTime value into a procedure that only requires the Date.  Today function returns the Current Date AND Time.  If you don't care about the time component, strip if off (As you are doing with ToShortDateString()) or set it to midnight or something

Comment: I have tried both. Using a date (not datetime variable) and also setting it to midnight, it has the same issue.

Comment: How are your parameters defined in the Proc?  Are you seeing this INSIDE the stored proc or in the application code before it sends it to the Stored Proc?  Also, are you using Azure SQL (since this could be something as simple as not taking UTC into account)

Comment: *"Using a date (not datetime variable)"*. They are exactly the same thing. Just as `Integer` and `Int32` are the same thing, so `Date` and `DateTime` are the same thing. If you want the current date and time then use `Date.Now`. If you want the current date with the time zeroed then use `Date.Today`.

Comment: Show us ALL the RELEVANT code, including the SQL. You show us one line and we're expected to just accept that everything else is exactly as it should be when it's not doing what it should do. If it's not working then you're doing something wrong. If you don't show us what you're doing, we can't see what's wrong with it.

Comment: Are you sure you don't have a timezone/DST problem between your client and the SQL server?

Comment: Hi Netmage, that was my thought as well but it still doesn't explain why passing #3/11/2021# from the VB client works fine but if I send date.today (it is the 11th on my pc) then it doesn't.

Comment: The SQL looks like this

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_Artemis_Tracking_SalesData]

 pShopID int,
 pStartDate Date,
 pEndDate Date,
 pDaily bit

 AS
BEGIN

 SET NOCOUNT ON;
 SELECT pEndDate

 - NOTE the ampersand before variable names was removed because stack overflow thought they were user names and wouldn't permit

Comment: If you have more information, you should update your question. My guess would be when you pass `#3/11/2021#` you pass a SQL `date` type, and without a time component timezone doesn't apply.

Answer (score 0):

To get rid of the confusion about midnight, let's pretend we added one minute to 3/11/2021 00:00:00. Now it is one minute after midnight on 3/11 or 3/11/2021 12:01:00 AM. As you can see you are sending 3/11/2021 12:00:00 AM. Nothing that happened on 3/11 will be included unless it happened on the stroke of midnight.

Simply add a day to the second parameter. That will take you to midnight on 3/11 or 12AM on 3/12

```
Dim Var = MyProc(#3/1/2021#, Today.AddDays(1))
```